# Why doesn't the following `exports = { z: function() {} };` work

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

**a.js**

```
exports = {
    z: function() {
        console.log('aZ');
    }
};
```

**main.js**

```
require('./a').z(); // error
```

Why does `require('./a')` return an empty object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your example you are overriding the `exports` global, and not updating it. If you replace your code with:

```
exports.z = function() {
    console.log('aZ');
};
```

it will work, because you are adding `z` to the actual exports object.

---

If you look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports), you will see:

> A reference to the module.exports that is shorter to type.

---

So you can imagine this situation:

```
var module = {
    exports: { /* some export stuff */ }
};

var exports = module.exports;
```

Now if you replace exports with `exports = something`, you aren't actually changing module.exports.

Comment: is `module.exports={}` can be used to simulate default (not named) export of `es6`?

Answer (score 1):

with commonjs you should use `module.exports` instead :

```
module.exports = {
    z: function() {
        console.log('aZ');
    }
};
```

and then :

```
require('./a').z();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing for beginners, but there are several exports formats that work slightly differently.

If you want to export a whole object as you say, you can replace the whole export like so:

```
module.exports = { z: function(){}};
```

You can also just attach stuff to the exports object directly

```
exports.z = function(){}
```

Finally, if you're using an ES6 compatible version you can do

```
export default { z: function(){}};
```